# Create a custom post type for a photo post

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, uploads

I am looking for a way to create a Photo Post type. Basically a post that is a title and a single image. Where I am getting stuck is the actual attaching an image to a post. I would like to have an image upload field in a metabox. I followed this [guide](http://austinpassy.com/2010/03/creating-custom-metaboxes-and-the-built-in-uploader/). I am able to see the WP upload box and I upload an image from my machine and click "Insert into Post". Then I publish the post. I don't know if the image is actually attached to that post though. I see the post in the database as well as the image as an "attachment" post_type.

Is this a good direction to go in if all I want is a simple attach a single image to a post along with a title?

Also, is there any way to simplify the media upload lightbox just for a certain post type? (Making it so the user doesn't need to know to click "Insert into Post" instead of "Save All Changes"?

Comment: why don't you use the feature image?

Comment: Are you able to use the full sized image? Or turn resizing off?

Comment: you can use set the width to the same size of your content, and set an standard height, if the image is smaller it won't affect anything...  I wrote it better below, also make sure your custom post type supports the thumbnail as Joshua said below...

Comment: Ah, ok. I have it figured out. What about the media upload lightbox, any way to simplify it? (i.e. Change layout) To make it easier to set a featured image? Or at least change the language?

Comment: I guess you have to assign a specific class to the image in order to make the Lightbox work... then check the update in my answer... that is what I would do...

Answer (score 1):

If you want just a title and an image I suggest you put this argument when registering the custom post type -> `'supports' => array( 'title', 'thumbnail' ),`

Answer (score 1):

In your functions.php... The size are relative... you can use your same size container and align the image to the left if it's the case...

```
 if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) { 
   add_image_size( 'post-photos', 900, 800);
 }
```

Custom Post Template

```
 <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
   <?php the_post_thumbnail('post-photos', array('class' => 'post-photos-image')); ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

If using lightbox and you need to assign the ligtbox class to the image:

In your post template into the loop

```
 <?php
    $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
 ?>
  <?php if($url !="") { ?>
      <img src="<?php echo $url; ?>" class="LIGHT-BOX CLASS">
  <?php } else {?>
               <!--Do not display image tag if there is none image attached-->
   <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Oops, sorry. By lightbox I meant the media upload window that pops up when you click "Set Featured Image". http://i.imgur.com/f0E5W.png I want to be able to simply the layout so the user knows to click "Set Featured Image" if they want to insert into the post.